# Codeigniter return Json from controller to dynamic table in view via Ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I get data from `Magento database` and I need to return it as an `Json object` and add data to the table in view. I'm getting a html response, not a valid json.

This is the error message :-

> DataTables warning: table id=order_list - Invalid JSON response. For
>   more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/1

Here is my controller code:

```
public function prepareJson(){

    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->setOrder('created_at', 'DESC')->setPageSize(25);
    $total_records = $this->orderModObj->get_total();
    $tableData = array();

    $jsonObj =new \stdClass();
    $jsonObj->sEcho = 5;
    $jsonObj->iTotalRecords = $total_records;
    $jsonObj->iTotalDisplayRecords = $total_records;

    foreach ($orders as $ordercus) {
        array_push($tableData, $ordercus);
    }
    $jsonObj->aaData = array($tableData);

    $tableJSON = json_encode($jsonObj);
    return $tableJSON;
}
```

Here is my view code

```
<table id="order_list" class="table table-bordered table-striped" data-page-length="25">
```

Here is the json structure

```
{
"sEcho": "5",
"iTotalRecords": 2708,
"iTotalDisplayRecords": 2708,
"aaData": [
    ["300000374", "16-11-2017", "16-11-2017", "title ", "charith m ", "<img src=\"http:\/\/mysite.lk\/dif.gif\" class=\"image\" alt=\"profile picture\">charith", "AUD 100.00", "<div class=\"processing\">Processing<\/div>", "<a class=\"tb-edit\" href=\"http:\/\/mysite.lk\/view\/300000374\">View <\/a>"]

]
}
```

Here is the javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#order_list').DataTable( {

    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,

    url: BASE_URL + 'order/prepareJson',
    method: 'post',
    data: { get_param: 'value' },
    dataType: 'json'
    //"ajax": " "
} );
$.ajax({
    success: function (feedback) {
        //console.log("feedback", feedback);
        $("#order_list").append($(feedback));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var names = feedback; `??

Comment: Please post your table field name so i can help you.

Comment: sorry, I need to append it to the view. I updated it. Akintunde

Comment: order_list is the id of the table in the html   NikuNj Rathod

Answer (score 0):

You need to either `print()` or `echo` the json and not `return` it.

```
$table_json = json_ecode($data);
echo $table_json;
```

Comment: I changed it but It comes same error message :- DataTables warning: table id=order_list - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Answer (score 0):

You do *not* have a valid JSON response.

Copy and paste your JSON here:

https://jsonlint.com/

You will see that your issue is the lack of proper quotes with your image tag. Even made Stack Overflow's code highlighter confused.

Comment: I edited my json here and here what i need is to generate a json like this from controller. but response comes as html when I load html.